# Unable to read excel file using ssis Script Source

Tags: excel, ssis

I have a case where I need to read an excel file with filtered rows using SSIS.

I've started testing the process but all I get when I look in my table is "System.__ComObject"

I'm sure I doing something stupid.

Thanks

```
Public Overrides Sub CreateNewOutputRows()

Dim xlApp = New Excel.Application

Dim wb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
Dim rw As Excel.Range
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\PosData\test.xlsx")


Dim visible As Excel.Range = wb.Sheets("Data").UsedRange.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible, Type.Missing)
For Each rw In visible.Rows
    Output0Buffer.AddRow()
    Output0Buffer.Column = rw.Cells(1, 1).ToString
Next

Output0Buffer.SetEndOfRowset()
End Sub
```

Comment: A practice I find helpful when debugging SSIS Script Tasks is to take the core logic and copy it into a .NET Console App so that I can step through and inspect the values. SSIS 2012 allows for setting breakpoints in dataflow scripts but in my mind it's still not as efficient as a full blown project. That said, shouldn't `ToString` be `ToString()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens sometimes when using the Interop.
All objects from Excel, in this case, are indeed COM Objects.

Use `Cells(1,1).Value` or `Cells(1,1).Value2` or `Cells(1,1).Text`. Wich fits best for you.
(Maybe you need to Cast or Convert the Cells to Range first)

Comment: That was it.  I was frustrated by the lack of properties appearing on the end of the cells.